# Hide rows based on cell value across 7 sheets excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, rows, autofilter

I searched the database to answer my question, but I couldn't find a similar situation.  The first 4 worksheets will always be identical in terms of last names displayed and the exact same range/# of empty cells.  The last 3 worksheets will also have the same situation with the exact same range/# of empty cells, but the range will be different than sheets 1-4.  I am looking to write VBA to hide entire rows based on cell value in Column A for every sheet.  Cells in column A are populated with formulas.

Worksheets 1-4 Range A9-A58:

```
Column A
Johnson             
Peterson
Anderson
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)
```

Worksheets 5-7 Range A16-A65:

```
Column A
Johnson
Peterson
Anderson
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)
```

Result I am looking for all worksheets:

```
Column A
Johnson
Peterson
Anderson
```

Here is the code I've tried:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'


    Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
    Rows("19:58").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Sheets("Sheet 2").Select
    Rows("19:58").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Sheets("Sheet 3").Select
    Rows("19:58").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Sheets("Sheet 4").Select
    Rows("19:58").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Sheets("Sheet 5").Select
    Rows("26:65").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Sheets("Sheet 6").Select
    Rows("26:65").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Sheets("Sheet 7").Select
    Rows("26:65").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

The problem is I have to manually select the empty rows and go sheet by sheet to make it work.  It would be nice to have something to hide the empty rows based on cell value within the specific range of each sheet.

I am open to how the VBA is written whether its with screen updating or auto filtering.  Thank you for your help/expertise!

Comment: Please provide any code you have tried thusfar.  Stack Overflow is a collaborative website intended to help with coding problems; it is not a code-for-you service.  If you are having issues getting started, use the *Macro Recorder* on the *Developer* tab, in Excel; perform the desired results, then review the generated code.  You will also want to look into a For loop, or a For Each loop, to account for looping between rows and between sheets.

Comment: @Cyril - I have updated the original post to reflect the code I have tried.

Comment: Have you looked into how loops work?  Specifically a For Loop?  That's the simplest concept to get where you're going.  I can give you a starter (for the first sheet), then you should be able to apply the logic to the next so many sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment, will give you a starting place for how looping works.

---

First we'll lay-out some parameters... 7 sheets, 2 defined ranges.  Let's start with the ranges:

```
Dim aStart as Long, aStop as Long, bStart as Long, bStop as Long
aStart = 19
aStop = 58
bStart = 26
bStop = 65
```

So you've got some ranges outlined by their rows (a is first range, b is second range).  Now what?  You want to look at each individual row between them, aka loop, to determine if it contains data or not, specifically in column A.

```
Dim i as Long  
For i = aStart to aStop
    If Cells( i, "A").Value = "" Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
```

Seems pretty simple, I hope.  The loop uses i as the row, while looking at the iterating rows in column A, one at a time.

This would look quite similar for bStart/bStop.  The only addition is making either happen... based on the sheet name/number.  There are umpteen ways for that to happen, and will leave it up to you to give it a whirl, as I've given you a lot so far, based on just recording a macro.